# Remove and add elements to table by comparing with other table (tables diff)

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a tagging system, I have one table (mapping between posts & tags) with the below columns:

```
post_id,tag_id
8,9
8,17
8,3
```

I have temporary table that contains the tags' id that should be for the post (it contain only id column)

```
id
 9
 3
66
```

I want to implement a functionality (SQL based) that user can modify tags (add/remove) - If user removes a tag, I want to know what ids to remove from the first table and if a new tag is being added, I want to know that it should be added to the first table.

In the example below, tag 17 will be deleted from the table and tag 66 will be added.

I'm looking for assistant in creating such a SQL query.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the setup:

```
CREATE TABLE mapping ( post_id INT, tag_id INT, PRIMARY KEY (post_id, tag_id));
INSERT INTO mapping VALUES (8,9),(8,17),(8,3);

CREATE TABLE temp_mapping (tag_id INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO temp_mapping VALUES (9),(3),(66);
```

We can use an outer join of one flavor or the other (LEFT or RIGHT) to find unmatched values in either direction.

We can use these to format new SQL statements, which can then be executed using PREPARE and EXECUTE to apply the changes.

```
SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM mapping WHERE post_id=8 AND tag_id IN (', GROUP_CONCAT(m.tag_id), ');') AS _sql
FROM mapping m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_mapping t ON m.tag_id = t.tag_id
WHERE m.post_id = 8 AND t.tag_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO mapping (post_id, tag_id) VALUES ', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(8, ', t.tag_id, ')')), ';')
FROM mapping m 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN temp_mapping t ON m.tag_id = t.tag_id AND m.post_id = 8 
WHERE m.tag_id IS NULL;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| _sql                                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| DELETE FROM mapping WHERE post_id=8 AND tag_id IN (17); |
| INSERT INTO mapping (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (8, 66);   |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a foreign key to table1.

```
Create table Table2 (id integer, PRIMARY KEY (id) )

Create table TABLE1 (postid integer, tagid integer
                     CONSTRAINT fk_ctagid FOREIGN KEY (tagid)
                     REFERENCES Table2(id)
                       ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

When a TAG ID is deleted from Table2, TAG Id is deleted from Table1 also.

Only Tag IDs in Table2 will be in TABLE1